# Error when trying to create virtualenv

Tags: python, virtualenv

I can't create a new virtual environment because of the following error:

```
$ virtualenv env
New python executable in env/bin/python
Installing distribute....done.
  Complete output from command /var/www/vhosts/example.com/...ython /var/www/vhosts/example.com/...stall /usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/v...ar.gz:
  error: Not a URL, existing file, or requirement spec: '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/virtualenv_support/pip-0.6.3.tar.gz'
----------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/virtualenv", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('virtualenv==1.4.5', 'console_scripts', 'virtualenv')()
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/virtualenv.py", line 537, in main
    use_setuptools=options.use_setuptools)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/virtualenv.py", line 630, in create_environment
    install_pip(py_executable)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/virtualenv.py", line 390, in install_pip
    filter_stdout=_filter_setup)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/virtualenv.py", line 598, in call_subprocess
    % (cmd_desc, proc.returncode))
OSError: Command /var/www/vhosts/example.com/...ython /var/www/vhosts/example.com/...stall /usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/v...ar.gz failed with error code 1
```

I have already searched the web but couldn't find any solution to this problem. I'm using Ubuntu 10.04.4 LTS with Python 2.6.5 and Virtualenv 1.7.2, any help appreciated. :)

Comment: *how* did you install you python interpreter? It doesn't look like the stock one, does it? Describe your setup a bit, as I'm pretty sure the problem hides there somewhere

Comment: I just found the problem (can't answer my own question right now because of my low reputation :( ) I installed virtualenv with `apt-get install python-virtualenv`, executing `apt-get purge python-virtualenv && easy_install virtualenv` solved it.

Comment: You should give a try to virtualenvwrapper: http://www.doughellmann.com/projects/virtualenvwrapper/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just figured it out myself: I tried to install virtualenv with `apt-get install python-virtualenv`.

Executing `apt-get purge python-virtualenv && easy_install virtualenv` solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing the same issue, and I did install "python-virtualenv" via "easy_install" instead of "apt-get".